# Como fazer um mock em uma classe android em tempo de execução?

Tags: android, testes, junit, mockito

Estou tendo uma certa dificuldade nos testes, queria saber se existe uma possibilidade de simular um retorno personalizado em um método em tempo de execução exemplo:

```
@RunWith(JUnit4.class)
public class TesteSmile {

    UserAndPass userAndPass = new UserAndPass();

    @Rule
    public ActivityTestRule<Exemplo> dashboard = new ActivityTestRule<>(Exemplo.class);

    @Mock
    public Customizacao customizacao = new customizacao(); 


    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        userAndPass = new UserAndPass();    
    }


    @org.junit.Test
    public void Main() throws InterruptedException {
        DashboardNewActivity dashboardNewActivitsy = dashboard.getActivity();

        customizacaoCliente.setTeste(true);

        when(customizacaoCliente.getTeste()).thenReturn(false);

        assertThat(false, customizacaoCliente.getTeste());      


        onView(withText("Item 1")).perform(click());

    }

    @After
    public void unregisterIdlingResource() throws Exception{
        //Intents.release();
    }
}
```

esse é só um exemplo, q fiz não irei postar tudo, mas só pra ter base, eu fiz mock de uma classe, nessa classe eu simulei um retorno falso, e no assert ele passa no teste, pois retorna a resposta que eu queria na chamada do get, o problema todo é, eu to fazendo testes visuais na aplicação e validando campos em geral, só que esse mock só moca a instancia local, a que criei dentro do teste, existe alguma forma de simular uma resposta fake na classe em execução? o teste roda no emulador do android studio, abre as telas, testa os campos, valida erros usando onview, mais em um determinado local eu quero trazer outros elementos, mas isso no tela visual(ui) na execução do emulador... há como fazer isso sem interferir diretamente no código da classe?

No final das contas eu não quero essa verificação de assert mas sim o que eu disse acima, o retorno visual. (o código é meramente um exemplo)

Comment: Se você está realizando testes instrumentados, você deve trocar `@RunWith(JUnit4.class)`por `@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)`